# Prove that $HN\leq G$, given that $H\leq G$, $N\trianglelefteq G$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am proving the second isomorphism theorem for groups. While proving that $HN\leq G$, a detail caught my eye.

Recall that $H\leq G$, $N\trianglelefteq G$ and to prove the above assertion I wanted the use the fact that if $H\leq G$ then $H\neq\emptyset$; and given $h_{1},\,h_{2}\in G$ implies $h_{1}h_{2}^{-1}\in H$.

So, clearly $HN\neq\emptyset$ because $e_{H}e_{N}\in HN$. Now, let $h_{1}n_{1},\,h_{2}n_{2}\in HN$. $h_{1}n_{1}(h_{2}n_{2})^{-1}=h_{1}n_{1}n_{2}^{-1}h_{2}^{-1}$ and I want to show that this belongs to $HN$. However, I don't see how. I know that $n_{1}n_{2}^{-1}\in N$ and, since $N\trianglelefteq G$, I can use the fact that $gng^{-1}\in N$, $\forall\,g\in G$.

**Note:** I know how to prove this if I only make use of the definition of subgroup. Just trying to see if it's possible to proceed in this fashion. Thanks.

Comment: $h_1n_1(h_2n_2)^{-1} = h_1n_1n_2^{-1}h_2^{-1} = (h_1h_2^{-1})(h_2n_1n_2^{-1}h_2^{-1})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier if you do $$h_1n_1h_2n_2 \in HN$$

and $$(hn)^{-1} \in HN$$

For the first:

$$h_1n_1h_2n_2 = h_1h_2(h_2^{-1}n_1h_2)n_2 \in HN$$ as $N$ is a normal subgroup.

For the other case, you can do something similar.